# Database migrating only working with 127.0.0.1 but access from website is localhost with homestead

Tags: laravel, database-migration, homestead

I have a Homestead setup in **Users/[username]/Homestead** and setup a vagrant to run several websites and this is working fine.

```
ip: 192.168.10.10
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox
mariadb: true

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    -
        map: '~/Sites/domain1'
        to: /home/vagrant/domain1
    -
        map: '~/Sites/domain2'
        to: /home/vagrant/domain2

sites:
    -
        map: domain1.app
        to: /home/vagrant/domain1/public
    -
        map: domain2.app
        to: /home/vagrant/domain2/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - domain1database
    - domain2database
```

I am running the **vagrant up** and **vagrant ssh** from the **Users/[username]/Homestead** directory.

The problem relates to the migrations and then accessing the database from the frontend such as https://domain1.app and https://domain2.app.

For example the **.env** with the following settings allows migrations from **/User/[username]/Sites/domain1**.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=domain1database
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

But I can only access these databases frontend with the following.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=domain1database
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

So at the moment I have to keep changing **127.0.0.1** and **localhost**.

Do the sites need to reside in the **Homestead** folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:**

I have managed to sort the issue with these settings in the **.env**.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.10.10
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=domain1database
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

The same above settings also works in **Sequel Pro**.